# Matching points from one collection with polygons from another in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

#### Find the number of points (in the forclosure collection) within the polygon defined from another collection (restaurants):

Foreclosure data format

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "643eeb300bd01c8a8087073a"
  },
  "datasetid": "foreclosure-2006-2016",
  "recordid": "629979c85b1cc68c1d4ee8cc351050bfe3592c62",
  "fields": {
    "parcel_number": "110138",
    "geocode": [
      36.0013755,
      -78.8922549
    ],
    "address": "217 E CORPORATION ST",
    "year": "2006"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -78.8922549,
      36.0013755
    ]
  },
  "record_timestamp": "2017-03-06T12:41:48-05:00"
}
```

Polygon data format:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6442c5f2749d228a02b7e422"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -78.9291768,
          36.03365
        ],
        [
          -78.8895483,
          36.0467802
        ],
        .
        .
        .
        
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  }
}
```

Manually I used it this way:

```
db.durham_nc_foreclosure.find({ geometry: { $geoWithin: { $polygon: [ [ -78.9291768, 36.03365], [ -78.8895483, 36.0467802], [ -78.9060312, 36.0183378], ...] } } })
```

I want to know how to do the same thing using aggregate pipeline and $lookup stage.

I tried out but facing an error:

My code:

```
[{
  $lookup: /**
 * from: The target collection.
 * localField: The local join field.
 * foreignField: The target join field.
 * as: The name for the results.
 * pipeline: Optional pipeline to run on the foreign collection.
 * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
 */
{
  from: 'restaurants_durham_geo_polygon',
    let:{foreClosureCoordinates:"$geometry"},
  pipeline:[
    {
      $geoWithin:{
        $polygon:{
          "$$foreClosureCoordinates"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  as: result
}
}
]
```

Comment: _"Find the number of points (in the forclosure collection) within the polygon defined from another collection (restaurants)"_ So, are you given `"_id"` from `restaurants_durham_geo_polygon` collection and you wish to find the count of all documents in `durham_nc_foreclosure` where its `"Point"` `"geometry"` is within the specified `restaurants_durham_geo_polygon` `"Polygon"` `"geometry"`?  Or do you need the total count of all _foreclosures_ within _any_ _restaurant polygon_?